# how to import a folder containing project in to eclipse as project

Tags: java, eclipse

Trying to backup the project, I browsed to the workspace in explorer and copied the folder containing all the project folders and files to my flash disk. Now I want to restore it and I dont know how? I copied the folder into workspace but no success. I tried import it into new project but folders are not copied and the files are copied to src folder. 
I now know that I should have done it from inside the eclipse using export as archive.

Answer (score 1):

Should work with File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace -> Select the parent folder that contains the project folders.

Comment: It worked now, What I was doing wrong was selecting the copied folder. The correct way is to select the folder containing the copied folder.

Comment: For example if the copied folder is yeti and it is at location /Users/mian/yeti then File-> import -> existing projects into workspace -> then select mian folder instead of yeti.

Comment: Sorry, its not working. it was picking another backup from the subfolder. instead of the one laying in the immediate folder.

Comment: does the folder you want to import have a .project file?

Comment: No I couldnt find one.

Comment: if the original project was created by eclipse then the folder should contain such a file. can you look into the original folder?

Comment: I dont have the original but yes you are right i think the .project file is not copied or it is lost.